# Write a program to compute the Taylor Series.

Tags: python, taylor-series

I am new to python and don't understand how to use the libraries properly. I am trying to write a program to compute the Taylor Series Approximation  of a function centered at 0 at a given x and n.

```
def fact(n):    #function to calculate n!
if n <= 0:
    return 1
else:
    return n * fact(n - 1)

#h= 0.00000000001

#def derivative(f,x,n):    #function that calculates the derivative of a 
 function at a specified x
    # return (f(x + h) - f(x - h)) /(2 * h)

 from sympy import *
 x = symbols('x')


def taylor(f,x,n):    
    for i in range(0,n):
      t = 0
      t = t + ((diff(f,x,n))/(fact(n))) * (x ** n)
      return t

  taylor(sin(x),1/32,1)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate, what's the question here? (What does not work, what did you expect instead ect)

Comment: I get a value error. I am trying to calculate the Taylor approximation of sin x or any other function at x= 1/32  centered at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works for me after I fixed stuff from your code. I used sympy factorial.

```
from sympy import *
x = symbols('x')

def taylor(f,x,x0, n):  
    t = 0  
    for i in range(0,n):
        t = t + ((diff(f,x,i).subs(x,x0))/(factorial(i))) * (x ** i)
    return t

pprint(taylor(sin(x),x,Rational(1,32),4))
```

and the answer I get is

```
   3              2                                    
  x ⋅cos(1/32)   x ⋅sin(1/32)                          
- ──────────── - ──────────── + x⋅cos(1/32) + sin(1/32)
       6              2
```